# Construct a circular phylogenetic tree

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, bioconductor, phylogeny

I have a table of genes and diseases to which they are related.I want to construct a phylogenetic tree and group the genes to their diseases.Below is a sample dataset,where gene1 column belongs to disease1 and gene2 belongs to disease2.Primarily gene1 and gene2 are related to each other,and are mapped to diseases they belong to.

```
gene1   gene2   disease1           disease2
AGTR1   ACHE    cancer              tumor
AGTR1   ACHE    parkinson's         asthma
ALOX5   ADRB1   myocardial infarct  heart failure
AR      ADORA1  breast cancer       anxiety disorder
```

I want to have a circular phylogenetic tree for my purposes,given in the link below:
http://itol.embl.de/itol.cgi

Any suggestions to do this in R or any softwares?

Thanks
[image]

Code I am running ,now:

```
d=read.csv("genes_disease.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
phyl_gad <-as.phylo(hclust(dist(d)))
 plot(phyl_gad,type="fan",edge.col=c("red","green","blue","orange","yellow","pink","magenta","white"),show.tip.label=FALSE)
```

If I do show.tip.label=TRUE,there are too many labels that get plotted and makes the tips cluttered up.

My modified dataset is only two columns now,one for gene,one for disease.

Comment: In `R` consider the `ape` package.  And you have a lot to explore over on the Bioconductor side.

Comment: I have been able to create this picture after modifying my dataset to one column of gene and only one column of disease instead in pairs.But I have too many clusters as seen in the figure.How can i make it more colorful instead of black, and add labels in the form of diseases?

Comment: title is misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I've done this before.  As Bryan said, you want to use the `ape` package.  Let's say that you have an `hclust` object.  For example,

```
library(ape)
fit<-hclust(d,method='ward')
plot(as.phylo(fit),type='fan',label.offset=0.1,no.margin=TRUE)
```

If you want to modify the colors of the ends of the trees, you can use `cutree` and the `tip.color` parameter.  This will create a repeating set of colors for the different clusters (e.g., `color=c('red','blue')` will have alternating blue and red text for the end of the branches.

```
nclus=...#insert number of clusters you want to cut to
color=...#insert a vector of colors here
fit<-hclust(d,method='ward')
color_list=rep(color,nclus/length(color))
clus=cutree(fit,nclus)
plot(as.phylo(fit),type='fan',tip.color=color_list[clus],label.offset=0.1,no.margin=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure what type of clustering method you want to use (I was using Ward's method), but that's how you do it.

Comment: So,d is my whole dataset in this case?and I want to use neighbor-joining method.

Comment: `d` is the distance matrix of your data.  For genes, I would look at the `dist.dna()` function, which is also in the `Ape` package.

http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/ape/html/dist.dna.html

Comment: I don't have any sequences as such,just the names of genes and the diseases they are related to.The above method works but the figure does not look good,so I am thinking to convert this data frame to Newick format,which can be imported to available softwares to make a nice impressive circular dendrogram.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to do was not a phylogeny but a clustering by distance. Here is a repeatable example.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)#geturl
library(rlist)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggtree)

#get the genes/ diseases info from internet
#example from http://www.musclegenetable.fr/
urllist<-paste0("http://195.83.227.65/4DACTION/GS/",LETTERS[1:24] )
theurl <- lapply(urllist, function(x) RCurl::getURL(x,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = T) ) )# wait
theurl2<-lapply(theurl, function(x) gsub("<span class='Style18'>","__",x))
tables <- lapply(theurl2, function (x) XML::readHTMLTable(x) )
tables2 <- lapply(tables, function(x) rlist::list.clean(x, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE) )
unlist1 = lapply(tables2, plyr::ldply)
newdf<-do.call(rbind, unlist1)
colnames(newdf)[4]<-"diseases"
colnames(newdf)[2]<-"Gene"
newdf$gene<-sub("([A-z0-9]+)(__)(.*)","\\1",newdf$Gene)
newdf$diseases<-sub("(\\* )","",newdf$diseases, perl=T)

#split info of several diseases per gene, and simplify text 
#to allow better clustering
newdf2<-as.data.frame(data.table::setDT(newdf)[, strsplit(as.character(diseases), "* ", fixed=TRUE), by = .(gene, diseases)
][,.(diseases = V1, gene)])
newdf2$disease<-sub("([A-z0-9,\\-\\(\\)\\/ ]+)( \\- )(.*)","\\1",newdf2$diseases)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("[0-9,]","",newdf2$disease)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("( [A-Z]{1,2})$","",newdf2$disease)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("(\\-)","",newdf2$disease)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",newdf2$disease)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("\\s*type.*","",newdf2$disease, ignore.case = T)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("(X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})","", newdf2$disease)
newdf2$disease<-gsub("( [A-z]{1,2})$","",newdf2$disease)
newdf2$disease<-sub("^([a-z])(.*)","\\U\\1\\E\\2",newdf2$disease, perl=T)
newdf2$disease<-trimws(newdf2$disease)
newdf2<-newdf2[,c(2,3)]

#make clustering and tree
newcasted <- reshape2::dcast(newdf2, gene ~ disease)
phyl_gad <-ape::as.phylo(hclust(dist(newcasted)))

#use names of genes and diseases in tree
DT <- data.table::as.data.table(newdf2)
newdf4<-as.data.frame(DT[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse=","), by = gene, .SDcols = 2])
newdf4$genemerge<-paste(newdf4$gene, newdf4$disease)
phyl_gad$tip.label<-newdf4$genemerge

#plot tree
ggtree::ggtree(phyl_gad, layout = "circular")+ ggtree::geom_tiplab2(offset=0.1, align = F, size=4)
```

[image]